# Sort array that contain alphanumeric words in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, sorting, nssortdescriptor

I have a array with 10 elements called products which is sorted by default, this is the current log now.

```
for (int i=0;i<products.count; i++)
{
     NSLog(@"%@",products[i]);
}
```

The Output:

```
Product1
Product10
Product2
Product3
Product4
Product5
Product6
Product7
Product8
Product9
```

I need to sort it in following order:

```
Product1
Product2
Product3
Product4
Product5
Product6
Product7
Product8
Product9
Product10
```

My current method is to scan out the numbers and sort based on that, I was wondering if there is any other way or and default method in iOS that does this or should I have to stick with my current method of scanning the numbers in each element and then sort??

Comment: May be you can change the Product Modul to include an int property, than when create the product object, setup the int value. After that just use this value to sort.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use this code to sort array. Use [NSNumericSearch](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/NSNumericSearch) to search the numeric value in string.

```
NSArray * products = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Product1",
                                                      @"Product10",
                                                      @"Product2",
                                                      @"Product3",
                                                      @"Product4",
                                                      @"Product5",
                                                      @"Product6",
                                                      @"Product7",
                                                      @"Product8",
                                                      @"Product9",
                                                      nil];

products = [products sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
        return [(NSString *)obj1 compare:(NSString *)obj2 options:NSNumericSearch];
    }];

NSLog(@"products : %@", products);
```

And the log display :

```
products : (
    Product1,
    Product2,
    Product3,
    Product4,
    Product5,
    Product6,
    Product7,
    Product8,
    Product9,
    Product10
)
```

Comment: this is called smart answer..thanks

Comment: @i_Looser thank you... :)

Comment: Using `NSNumericSearch | NSCaseInsensitiveSearch` ought to ensure capitalization doesn't mess up the sort too

Answer (score -1):

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDesc = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"YourKeyName" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];


self.products = [[self.products sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDesc, nil]] mutableCopy];
```

For more details [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Arrays.html)

Comment: This is incorrect. have you checked your code?

Comment: Returns products === (
    Product1,
    Product10,
    Product2,
    Product3,
    Product4,
    Product5,
    Product6,
    Product7,
    Product8,
    Product9
)

Comment: Yes I have checked before posting my answer.

Comment: And at that time its returns correct values? Wonderss